# Linux Connecting USB printer with IP?

Tags: printing, localhost, port-forwarding

I have android tablet with USB port,
I have connected thermal printer with this USB port,
Now I can print receipts easily from many playstore programs having USB printer option but one of my program requires network printer ... means I have to put IP address ... what should I write in the IP address for USB printer ... Do I have to forward USB port to Localhost ... Is there any way?
Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/892260/edit) your question and add which version of Ubuntu you are using in your tablet.

Comment: This doesn't seems to have anything to do with Ubuntu. If it does please edit your question and clarify.